# Нужно ли двоеточие перед кавычками? Есть ли ошибки в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, двоеточие

Однако многие из нас начинают выполнять работу, не подумав об опасных факторах:  кто-то не придает им должного внимания, прикрываясь фразой: «всегда так делал, и ничего не случалось», кто-то из нас не научился определять риски...

Comment: О втором двоеточии в предложении: https://orfogrammka.ru/справочник/правила_русской_орфографии_и_пунктуации_лопатин/. Оно нежелательно всегда, и случаев, когда  по условиям контекста взаимозаменяемость знаков невозможна, предельно мало.

Answer (score 1):

**Однако многие  начинают выполнять работу, не подумав об опасных факторах: кто-то не придает им должного внимания, прикрываясь фразой «всегда так делал, и ничего не случалось», кто-то  не научился определять риски...**

1) Двоеточие не нужно: дословное высказывание в роли несогласованного определения (фразой какой).

2) ***Из нас*** — возможно, лишнее слово.